# Is "Tasks for life" correct?

Tags: phrases, grammaticality

"Tasks for life" - Would such a phrase be apropriate for a brand ?
Is it correct to say it that way ?
I want to create a task managing site, where people would manage their tasks in life.

PS: English is not my native language, so please, excuse me.

Comment: I think you should be more specific. What are you trying to express with the phrase? What is the brand about?

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: Also, I didn't quite know, which tags were apropriate, so feel free to retag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all the little info you've provided us with, I'd call it:

> Tasks of life.

The above phrase is pretty clear and powerful, while your original phrase, *tasks for life* is ambiguous, as it may either mean:

1) tasks **for** life (the usual, simple meaning)
2) tasks that require a lifetime to complete (kind of a negative meaning), like when you say, for example, *This injury will stay with me for life.*

Having an ambiguous phrase in this case isn't really anything one usually wants, therefore I'd recommend avoiding it.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, "for life" typically means "for the rest of one's life." Even if people recognize that it's not your intended meaning, it's still a meaning that will occur to a native speaker.

It could be either negative (RiMMer's example above) or positive ("I'm struggling now, but if I win the lottery, I'll be set for life")

However, I don't think what you mean is "We'll give you more and more tasks forever until you're dead," so I think you should avoid "tasks for life."